# Why do we get rings in the Spontaneous Parametric Down conversion (SPDC) process?

Tags: optics, photons, quantum-optics, non-linear-optics, photonics

In the SPDC process, the phase-matching conditions between the o-rays and/or e-rays have to hold for the down-conversion process to take place. Say we have a non-collinear phase-matching at the plane formed between the pump and the optical axis of the crystal, and the signal and idler photons exit the crystal at certain angles with respect to the pump.  [image]

Now, I don't understand how we can get circular rings from this. If we consider signal and idler on a different plane for let's say Type-I SPDC, The polarization of the photons would be orthogonal to that of the pump. This polarization would have components both along the pump-optical axis plane and orthogonal to it. This, in turn, would affect the magnitude of the k vectors as the refractive index depends on the polarization. Now the phase-matching would happen at angles different from the previous case. But the usual output of a Type I SPDC is a ring indicating that the signal and idler form the same angles on every plane. How are such rings obtained? Where is my understanding wrong here?
**Note**: Here the planes I am referring to are planes on which these phase-matched vectors may lie, always containing the pump wave vector.

Comment: I was about to ask the same question. Maybe this comment will bump it.   I can take a guess for Type II SPDC that the directions described by the two cones arise from $k_s$ being rotated about the $k_p$ direction and vice versa.   It would be nice to get a answer from someone who knows the answer.